# Why the request size increases 3 times?

Tags: request, size

i am working with angular 8 and nodejs to upload files. i user formdata to transfer the file from angular to node. In node i use multer to parse the formdata(Content-Type is left empty).

The functionality works fine.

My question are:

Why does the request size increases 3 times ? the file is sent just as i receive it from the file input

example:

[original file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTa4j.png)

[request sent to node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mif3.png)

2. Is there a better way to send files between angular and node regarding the request size?

Comment: Click on the request as shown here in DevTools and check what is sent to the back end, check the 'Request Headers' section. my guess is that your front-end application adds multiple HTTP headers to the outgoing request e.g (token, data about the browser). I think you can compress the request in some format and send it to the backend, check for gzip for example.

Comment: If i add a file with size of 10 MB the request size will be 45mb, indeed i add token and cors for the request. I could go for gzip but it would not solve the actual problem.

Comment: i found the problem:
1. the response header is application json
2. i send the file back ass array buffer using res.send() with content-type application json.

Comment: how could i send the mongoose object that contains the details and the buffer of file from node to angular without increasing the size